# c# and regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to get `100` and `example` from this string

```
?connect:100/username:example/
```

I searched in google but cannot find some useful regex patterns form my solution

Please help

Comment: You can split by '/' first and then by ':'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    Regex RegexObj = new Regex(":(?<Number>\\d+)/.+?:(?<Text>\\w+)/");
    Match MatchResults = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString);
    while (MatchResults.Success) {
        for (int i = 1; i < MatchResults.Groups.Count; i++) {
            Group GroupObj = MatchResults.Groups[i];
            if (GroupObj.Success) {

            } 
        }
        MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex:

```
\?connect:([0-9]+)/username:([^/]*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex for this, use Linq:

```
var url = "?connect:100/username:example/";
var data = url.Substring(1, url.Length-2).Split('/')
                                         .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                                         .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);

Console.WriteLine(data["connect"]); // 100
Console.WriteLine(data["username"]); // example
```

You could remove the `SubString(1, url.Length-2)` call if you got the string back without the starting `?` and trailing `/`.